# C# Method Calling Several times

Tags: c#, performance, methods

I have a method `GetNames()` that returns comma separate strings from an array. The array contains a list of names. I am calling this method in my ViewModels three times. Will it make any performance difference between one call one time and store that return values in an object.
Or 2. by calling that method each time.

1.

```cs
string nameParm = GetNames();
_metaController.GetNamedetails(nameParm); //Some operation
_metaController.UpdateNamedetails(nameParm, "Approved");
```

2.

```cs
_metaController.GetNamedetails(GetNames()); //Some operation
_metaController.UpdateNamedetails(GetNames(), "Approved");
```

Comment: Answer will depend on some variables: how big list of names can be? Is there a chance that `GetNames` return different names when you call it multiple times(how often list of names will change)?. When you using variable you will "tell" next reader of the code that same names should be passed to the next methods. When calling `GetNames()` multiple times, you will probably tell next reader/developer that "current" names should be passed to the methods.

Comment: Answer to performance question - benchmark it, run methods with profiler and compare results.

Comment: Depends on implementation of `GetNames()`. If you have a member variable that is returned by `GetNames()` then doesn't matter. In fact in 1st case you will be creating one local variable for no reason. But if `GetNames()` have some logic to prepare list then 1st method will be better.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if I understand your question correctly, but yes it will make a 'performance difference'. See, every time the line `GetNames()` will be written, it will execute the method.

Assuming you have a console app, you can easily verify this by writing `Console.WriteLine("Method hit!")` in your `GetNames` method. If you start your project, you will see that you have `Method hit!` two times in a row.

You could also check for such a behavior by setting a break point in your method and debugging your project.

So you would be better of using your first method 99% of the time.